# Usage of Firestore in React doesn't work - Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

it's very likely that I've done an obvious mistake but I can't find it, even after many hours of research.

Let me tell briefly you what I've done:

> 1. npm install firebase --save
> 2. `import firebase from "firebase";`
> 3. `firebase.initializeApp({ ... });`

> After compiling the following error message is shown:
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/luisgaspar/Desktop/Coding/React-Learning/chat-app-1/src'

Do you have suggestions on where my mistake could be?

Comment: Can you still share the complete code? So if issue if with serviceWorker module we can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its actually due to the new upgraded version of firebase to 9.0.1 . You can find the official documentations here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade  .
Also if you wish to use the previous commands as in version 9, you should try like below :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

Comment: That import solved my question, thank you!

Comment: That's what the community is for. Do upvote if you want to.